# EMF: Find the Image to an EClass with only the EPackage?

Tags: rcp, emf

i have an EPackage and from this Package one EClass. All i want to get is the Image that is associated with the EClass, how can i get that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found out myself: you have to get the adapterFactory over the gloabl registry and from there you can get access to your label provider. from there it should be easy

Comment: How to get the adapterFactory from the global registry?